# Can I assign Typora themes on a file-by-file basis?

Tags: css, markdown

I'm using Typora on a Mac and have begun building my own CSS theme to display nested lists with graphical lines instead of bullet symbols for displaying file hierarchies.

Is it possible to have my Theme be automatically used for the specific Typora files that have my file hierarchies, and use another Theme for other files, or must I change the Typora style manually back and forth, for each file that I open?

If this is not built in to Typora, does anyone have an idea for how to implement this automatically in some other way?

Thanks.

Comment: I contacted the Typora developer (hi@typora.io) and they replied that this is currently not supported but may be in the future. So I'm looking for workarounds.

Comment: One workaround I've considered is to have a specific string in the filename, e.g., "`MyFiles.outline.md`" and use a triggered script system like Keyboard Maestro to look for that string (`.outline.`) every time a file is opened in Typora and automatically invoke the appropriate Theme -- and use a different theme for all other Typora files.